# Using JavaScript operators in a switch statement with event.code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement in which I try to map keyboard shortcuts to a horizontal full page scrolling:

- <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
  scrolls forward
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> scrolls
  backward
- <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> goes to the beginning
  of the page
- <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> scrolls to the end
  of the page

Here is my attempt, which isn’t working:

```
switch (event.code) {
  case "Space" || "PageDown" || "ArrowRight": {
    scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
    break
  }
  case "PageUp" || "ArrowLeft": {
    scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
    break
  }
  case "Home" || "ArrowUp": {
    scrollAmount = 0
    break
  }
  case "End" || "ArrowDown": {
    scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth
    break
  }
}
```

How do I propely use the operators in this case?

Comment: Use the fall-through feature of the switch statement. A matched case will run until a break (or the end of the switch statement) is found. You need to define all cases.

Comment: I had my answer typed up just before the question was closed as duplicate. I'd like to share it via a codepen, anyway: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/JjjLVKJ?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [specify each case separately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Multi-case_-_single_operation):

```
switch (event.code) {
  case "Space":
  case "PageDown":
  case "ArrowRight": {
    scrollAmount += window.innerWidth
    break
  }
  case "PageUp":
  case "ArrowLeft": {
    scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
    break
  }
  case "Home":
  case "ArrowUp": {
    scrollAmount = 0
    break
  }
  case "End":
  case "ArrowDown": {
    scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth
    break
  }
}
```